# Display a collection in a cell?

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable

Im using a CellTable to display my data. But my data has fields that is a collection of string. I wonder if there's any recommendation for this purpose. What do you do in this case?

Comment: You must find out first, what data you have, and how *you* want to display the data. Is there just one collection of strings, and do you want to display each string in the collection in its own column? Is the collection sorted at all? Does it have a fixed length... etc.

Comment: @ChrisLercher What i want is display a collection of strings in a cell of cellTable. I just dont have any idea about this part :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a [`Cell`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/Cell.html) (easiest is to extend [`AbstractCell`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/AbstractCell.html) as you only have to implement the `reder` method) that displays your data (i.e. serialize it to HTML).

Comment: Thank you. I made my own custom cell that matches my demand. Quite simple but that's enough for me. If anyone want to take a look at the code, visit http://pastebin.com/KzSW9Tdc